# How to call another module without returning to the first one after completion?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2013

This is probably the dumbest question I've ever asked here, but it's hard to find answers to things like this.

I have a program with a bunch of modules/subs that each calculate a different variable. They're pretty complex, so I like to keep them separate. Now I want an earlier module to skip to another module based on user input. I thought I could use the `call (sub name)` method for this, but then the program returns to where the call line was and continues on that module from where it left off.

Example:

Module 1:

```
Sub NewPracticeSub()

    Call otherpracticesub

    MsgBox ("We've gone back to this sub... :(")

End Sub
```

Module 2:

```
Sub otherpracticesub()

    MsgBox ("We're in the other practice sub!")

End Sub
```

I don't want it to return to Module 1. What can I do to have it switch control to Module 2 without it then returning to complete Module 1 upon completion of Module 2?

I feel like I just used the most confusing language possible to explain all of this, but thank you for your help anyways!!

*Edit: I know I used the words module and sub interchangeably, and I know they're different. I like to keep each sub (which are each very large in my program) in their own modules because it's easier to keep track of them, and easier to explain/demonstrate the application flow to other people.*

Comment: *I don't want it to return to Module 1.*  **Why not?** This is how the call stack works. John's answer below is a good workaround, but probably you need to better organize your subroutines and calls.

Comment: You could use `End` within your subroutines, but this aborts ALL run-time procedures, kills all variables, etc. and should probably be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than using the ugly `End` statement which I will describe below (and strongly recommend you to avoid), I'm not aware of any way to circumvent the call stack.  Even John's response necessarily returns to the calling procedure, and evaluates another statement to determine whether to proceed or end.

This may yield undesirable outcomes, which is why I hesitate to recommend it, in favor of properly structuring your code, loops, etc., with respect to the call stack.

In any case, here is how you can use the `End` statement within your child subroutines, without needing any sort of public/global variables. This still allows you the flexibility to decide when & where to invoke the `End` statement, so it need not always be invoked.

```
Sub NewPracticeSub()

    Call otherpracticesub, True

    MsgBox ("We've gone back to this sub... :(")

End Sub

Sub otherpracticesub(Optional endAll as Boolean=False)

    MsgBox ("We're in the other practice sub!")

    If endAll then End '## Only invoke End when True is passed to this subroutine
End Sub
```

**Why I say [this method should be avoided](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251671.aspx)**, via MSDN:

> "Note The End statement stops code execution abruptly, without
>   invoking the Unload, QueryUnload, or Terminate event, or any other
>   Visual Basic code. Code you have placed in the Unload, QueryUnload,
>   and Terminate events of forms and class modules is not executed.
>   Objects created from class modules are destroyed, files opened using
>   the Open statement are closed, and memory used by your program is
>   freed. Object references held by other programs are invalidated.
>
> The End statement provides a way to force your program to halt. For
>   normal termination of a Visual Basic program, you should unload all
>   forms. Your program closes as soon as there are no other programs
>   holding references to objects created from your public class modules
>   and no code executing."

Comment: I decided to simply bite the bullet and spend a few hours rearranging my subroutines in a better manner, so that I don't have to deal with the End method at all. Thank you for the advice! It was worth the effort, and now I don't have to worry about more things going wrong.

Comment: @TheTreeMan it sucks, but you're right, in the long run, you'll have a more stable program/application. Cheers!

Comment: The only time you should ever need to use END is if you want to reset global variables. But that usually means you've made some grave coding errors to get in that situation.

Answer (score 2):

I think all you're looking for is the command `Exit Sub` which will make the program leave the subroutine without continuing any further, But the way you usually want to do this is, rather than calling a `Sub`, rather call a `Function` that returns a boolean value.

So, for example:

```
Public Function MyFunc() as Boolean
   ....
   If [good] MyFunc = True
   Else MyFunc = False
End Function
```

Then you could do something along the lines of:

```
Sub MyCallingSub()
   ...
   If MyFunc = True then Exit Sub
   Else ...
End Sub
```

It just adds in A LOT more felxibility and ability to choose whether you want to continue further in your sub or not.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Agreed.  Put your calls in an If/Then loop.  VBA is always going to return to whatever Sub/Module you started from, and the only way to end it is to return to that Sub/Module and Exit Sub.

Answer (score 0):

It will always return but that doesn't mean its a problem. I suggest you use Exit Sub as follows:

Sub NewPracticeSub()

```
Call otherpracticesub

**Exit Sub**
'Nothing more can execute here so its no longer a worry
```

End Sub

Module 2:

Sub otherpracticesub()

```
MsgBox ("We're in the other practice sub!")
```

End Sub